# Getting href using xpath without opening Browser

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, href, selenium-chromedriver

I have a requirement in which I have to download around 900 documents from different webpages.

I have url of webpages and the xpath of each document to be downloaded.

Currently what I am doing is that reading the url and xpath from database, opening the browser ( Chrome ) and locating the link using xpath and then downloading the document.

The problem is that the chrome has to be opened for around 100 times for downloading all the documents, which causes performance issue.

So is there any way to download the documents without opening the browser and using xpath ( **like if I can get href using Xpath without opening the browser** and then use Apache http client to download document ) ?

**Note** - I am using Selenium for it and I don't want to use href directly to download the documents

Comment: What exact `performance issue` are you facing? Can you share your code trials?

Comment: Would it not be better to use `wget` if you have all the href links stored? Or are the download links dynamic?

Comment: Download links can be dynamic for some website that's why using xpath

Comment: @DebanjanB - Chrome gets opened many time which consumes a lot of time, I want to eliminate that

Comment: @bharatbhushan , why do you need to open new Chrome session for each page instead of just using `get(URL)` in `for` loop?

Comment: i second Andersson... why are you re-opening the instance?
And besides, you should have several instances running in parallel(one for each core in the computer) to maximise performance

Comment: @Andersson - By opening chrome I meant opening webpage, opening all the web pages take time.
If there is any way to get href using xpath without opening chrome/webpage then it will be very helpful

Comment: You need to use GhostDriver, you can download it from seleniumhq.org/downloads. And search the rest of the details on google.

Comment: @bharatbhushan You can do it with python. Read about Web Scraping with `beautifulsoup` library

Answer (score 0):

You can check phantomJS;

First download the appropriate version from http://phantomjs.org/download.html and paste into same folder with code.py

It's a example from my code for pagination at https://www.tripadvisor.com.tr/

```
from selenium import webdriver
url = "https://www.tripadvisor.com.tr/Restaurants-g293974-Istanbul.html"
executable_path1 = './phantomjs'
mekan_linkler = []
div_mekanlar1 = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@href]")
for i in div_mekanlar1:
     x = i.get_attribute('href')
     y = 'http'+x[5:]
     mekan_linkler.append(y)
nextpage = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='EATERY_LIST_CONTENTS']/div[3]/div//a[contains(.,'Sonraki')]")
nextpage.click()
```

For more information, check http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.phantomjs.webdriver